# How to make the terminal display user@machine in bold letters?

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters

I have seen in some screen-shots (can't remember where on the web) that the terminal can display the `[username@machine /]$` in bold letters. I'm looking forward to getting this too because I always find myself scrolling through long outputs to find out with difficulty the first line after my command.

How can I make the user name etc. bold or coloured?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using the bash shell or some other shell?

Comment: Gnome Terminal bash.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the `PS1` prompt variable in your `~/.bashrc` file like this:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '
```

To make it colored (and possibly bold - this depends on whether your terminal emulator has enabled it) you need to add escape color codes:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Here, everything not being escaped between the `1;91m` and `0m` parts will be colored in the `1;91` color (bold red). Put these escape codes around different parts of the prompt to use different colors, but remember to reset the colors with `0m` or else you will have colored terminal output as well. Remember to source the file afterwards to update the current shell: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Why not use 31 for red?  91 does not seem to be a standard code.

Comment: @jw013 The range 90-97 are equivalent to the 30-37 range if used as bold i.e. `1;31` and `1;91`. Using normal font weight, the 90-97 range gives more brighter colors than the other.

Answer (score 48):

Find where your `PS1` is set in your `.bashrc` and insert `'\[\e[1m\]'` at the beginning and `\[\e[0m\]` at the end.

- `\[` and `\]` are necessary so the shell knows the mess inside takes up 0 space on the screen, which prevents some screwed up behavior when doing line-editing.  You don't need to worry too much about it.
- `\e[` is known as the CSI (control sequence introducer).  You'll see it used in most of the codes listed on the referenced Wikipedia page. `\e`  means the escape character.
- If you look in the SGR table on the Wikipedia page, you'll see the 1 is the number for bright/bold text, and 0 is for reset.  Thus `CSI 1m` turns on bold and `CSI 0m` resets the font so the rest of your text is normal.

Wikipedia has a full [list of ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) that you can use if your terminal emulator supports it.

## Edit

For portability and readability, you should use `tput` instead of hard-coding escape codes.  The only downside is the `tput` approach won't work with terminals that support ANSI codes but have broken or missing terminfo databases, but in that case the broken terminfo is a bigger problem as many of your console apps that rely on terminfo may not work properly.

Here's an example of what I do in my `.bashrc`:

```
# color names for readibility
reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)
black=$(tput setaf 0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
user_color=$green
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] && { user_color=$red; }
PS1="\[$reset\][\[$cyan\]\A\[$reset\]]\[$user_color\]\u@\h(\l)\
\[$white\]:\[$blue\]\W\[$reset\][\[$yellow\]\$?\[$reset\]]\[$white\]\
\\$\[$reset\] "
```

Here's what a genericized version of mine would look like.  The `0` is the exit status of the last command.

[image: PS1 screenshot]

Comment: Nice and explanatory answer, +1. Still I found *hesse*'s answer more to the point, so I chose it instead.

Comment: When I tried this, I ran into a problem like [Terminal prompt not wrapping correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly). Do you? Do you have updated escape sequences?

Answer (score 8):

This is the default prompt that you get in cygwin bash shell:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

[image]

```
\[\e]0;\w\a\] = Set the Window title to your current working directory
\n            = new line
\[\e[32m\]    = Set text color to green
\u@\h         = display username@hostname
\[\e[33m\]    = Set text color to yellow
\w            = display working directory
\[\e[0m\]     = Reset text color to default
\n            = new line
\$            = display $ prompt
```

References:

- See `man bash` and check the `PROMPTING` section.
- See [ANSI escape code - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Nice, I added a new line before the **[user@host]** which makes each command yet more readable (it should be set so by default on terminal imo).

Answer (score 2):

I use this shell function to get text attributes in the terminal:

```
color () {
  if [ -z "$1" -a -z "$2" -a -z "$3" ]; then
    echo "\033[0m"
    return
  fi
  case $1 in
    black)   color_fg=30;;
    red)     color_fg=31;;
    green)   color_fg=32;;
    yellow)  color_fg=33;;
    blue)    color_fg=34;;
    magenta|purple) color_fg=35;;
    cyan)    color_fg=36;;
    white)   color_fg=37;;
    -)       color_fg='';;
    *)       color_fg=39;;
  esac
  case $2 in
    bold)      color_bd=1;;
    italics)   color_bd=3;;
    underline) color_bd=4;;
    inverse)   color_bd=7;;
    strike)    color_bd=9;;
    nobold)      color_bd=22;;
    noitalics)   color_bd=23;;
    nounderline) color_bd=24;;
    noinverse)   color_bd=27;;
    nostrike)    color_bd=29;;
    -)         color_bd='';;
    *)         color_bd=0
  esac
  case $3 in
    black)   color_bg=40;;
    red)     color_bg=41;;
    green)   color_bg=42;;
    yellow)  color_bg=43;;
    blue)    color_bg=44;;
    magenta|purple) color_bg=45;;
    cyan)    color_bg=46;;
    white)   color_bg=47;;
    -)       color_bg='';;
    *)       color_bg=49;;
  esac
  s='\033['
  if [ -n "$color_bd" ]; then
    s="${s}${color_bd}"
    if [ -n "$color_fg" -o -n "$color_bg" ]; then
      s="${s};"
    fi
  fi
  if [ -n "$color_fg" ]; then
    s="${s}${color_fg}"
    if [ -n "$color_bg" ]; then
      s="${s};"
    fi
  fi
  if [ -n "$color_bg" ]; then
    s="${s}${color_bg}"
  fi
  s="${s}m"
  echo "$s"
  unset s color_bd color_bg color_fg
}
```

Then to use it:

```
color_reset=`color`
color_grbd=`color green bold`
color_bubd=`color blue bold`
PS1="\[${color_grbd}\][\u@\h]\[${color_reset}\]:\[$color_budb}\]\w\[${color_reset}\]> "
```

This gives me `[username@hostname]:cwd>` where `username@hostname` are bold green and `cwd` is bold blue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suppose I also had to copy all of the above in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, I set that in my `~/.bashrc` file and use it to set my prompt.  I even change the colors depending on the system I'm on.

Answer (score 1):

To make it look like a default Ubuntu prompt, add

`export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h\e[0;39m\]:\e[1;34m\]\w\e[0;39m\]$\[\e[0m\] '`

in your `~/.bashrc`.

This will produce the well-known green `user@host` (bold), followed by a non-bold white colon, followed by your working directory in bold blue, followed by a `$` sign, a space, and your command in non-bold white letters:

[image: Ubuntu Bash prompt]