# Terminal prompt not wrapping correctly

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I have an issue where if I type in very long commands in bash the terminal will not render what I'm typing correctly. I'd expect that if I had a command like the following:

```
username@someserver ~/somepath $ ssh -i /path/to/private/key
myusername@something.someserver.com
```

The command should render on two lines. Instead it will often wrap around and start writing over the top of my prompt, somewhat like this:

```
myreallylongusername@something.somelongserver.comh -i /path/to/private/key
```

If I decide to go back and change some argument there's no telling where the cursor will show up, sometimes in the middle of the prompt, but usually on the line *above* where I'm typing.

Additional fun happens when when I <kbd>Up</kbd> to a previous command.
I've tried this in both gnome-terminal and terminator and on i3 and Cinnamon. Someone suggested it was my prompt, so here that is:

```
\[\033[01;32m\]\u:\[\033[01;34m\] \W\033[01;34m \$\[\033[00m\]
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>, `reset`, and `clear` all do what they say, but when I type the command back in or <kbd>Up</kbd> the same things happens.

I checked and `checkwinsize` is enabled in bash. This happens on 80x24 and other window sizes.

Is this just something I learn to live with? Is there some piece of magic which I should know? I've settled for just using a really short prompt, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: So using the command `env -i bash --norc` fixes it. The $COLUMNS and $LINES match. Does that mean that there's something funny with my .bashrc?

Comment: So I commented out my .bashrc and wound up isolating my prompt as the problematic part, specifically the coloration syntax involved. What's wrong with the PS1 above?

Comment: `\[\033[01;32m\]\u: \[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[01;34m\] \$ \[\033[0m\]` seems to avoid the weirdness in the behavior - but don't know if it respects your original prompt completely...

Comment: As per [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/619127/171296), use ```tput smam```

Comment: set term=XTERM worked for me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Non-printable sequences should be [enclosed in `\[` and `\]`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt). Looking at your *PS1* it has a unenclosed sequence after `\W`. But, the second entry is redundant as well as it repeats the previous statement *"1;34"*.

```
\[\033[01;32m\]\u:\[\033[01;34m\] \W\033[01;34m \$\[\033[00m\]
                  |_____________|               |_|
                         |                       |
                         +--- Let this apply to this as well.
```

As such this should have intended coloring:

```
\[\033[1;32m\]\u:\[\033[1;34m\] \W \$\[\033[0m\]
                               |_____|
                                  |
                                  +---- Bold blue.
```

Keeping the *"original"* this should also work:

```
\[\033[1;32m\]\u:\[\033[1;34m\] \W\[\033[1;34m\] \$\[\033[0m\]
                                  |_|         |_|
                                   |           |
                                   +-----------+-- Enclose in \[ \]
```

---

#### Edit:

The reason for the behavior is because `bash` believes the prompt is longer then it actually is. As a simple example, if one use:

```
PS1="\033[0;34m$"
       1 2345678
```

The prompt is believed to be 8 characters and not 1. As such if terminal window is 20 columns, after typing 12 characters, it is believed to be 20 and wraps around. This is also evident if one then try to do backspace or <kbd>Ctrl+u</kbd>. It stops at column 9.

However it also does not start new line unless one are on last column, as a result the first line is overwritten.

If one keep typing the line should wrap to next line after 32 characters.

Comment: If you have - or anyone - has an explanation as to what exactly in the original sequence caused the line to repeat over itself, I'd be interested in knowing that. Also +1 for how you showed this visually.

Comment: @illuminÉ: Have not looked at the source, but added an update with a note on behavior from observation.

Comment: Just in case you are facing any problems, you can use this website to create a new one - http://bashrcgenerator.com/

Comment: This is amazing, thank you @Runium - would you mind sharing how you knew this? I would love to find some documentation on this.

Comment: @nycynik: Observation. I guess the closest to documentation on this is the source code ...

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes.

Comment: I have the default prompt in Debian: `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`. How should I repair this one?

Comment: i used to use `\e[ ... m` for the color codes and had this problem too. Now, switching to `\[\033[ ... m\[` it's all fine!

Comment: In my case this was only part of the solution.  The other issue was that the admins had pre-set `PROMPT_COMMAND` which was interfering somehow with prompt printing.

Answer (score 105):

It is mostly to do with the size of the window assumed by the terminal is not the same as your actual window size. If you are using bash, you can try this.

```
$ shopt checkwinsize
```

If you don't get

```
checkwinsize    on
```

Then activate it with

```
$ shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Then just attempt running another command (like `ls`) or resizing the window once, the above works for me every time.

For Redhat systems particularly, the issue is often caused by misconfiguring `~/.bashrc` not to call `/etc/bashrc`. Normally, bash loads `~/.bashrc` which is expected to call `/etc/bashrc`, which by default contains `shopt -s checkwinsize`.

Comment: Had the same problem with OS X, apparently if you call "login" to start your terminal, it starts bash in a way that reads /etc/bashrc, but if you just call straight to bash, the ~/.bashrc doesn't source things by default so you get the odd wrapping effect.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Colors were not on in this particular server, calling correct `/etc/bashrc`, everything else was good to go...turns out this is the cause of the wrapping issues.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61608/2221

Comment: Looks like a good solution. But it doesn't work in my ssh session, though. Not sure why. I have run the command `shopt -s checkwinsize` in the ssh session. But the wrapping persists.

Comment: This was precisely my problem - a user .bashrc wasn't calling /etc/bashrc, and so making a mess.

Comment: @QiangXu I had to resize my window once more, then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 33):

I once read somewhere (don't know where anymore) that using `\001` and `\002` instead of `\[` and `\]` can solve this issue. It did for me.

By the way, defining PS1 does not have to look ugly.

```bash
green="\001$(tput setaf 2)\002"
blue="\001$(tput setaf 4)\002"
dim="\001$(tput dim)\002"
reset="\001$(tput sgr0)\002"

PS1="$dim[\t] " # [hh:mm:ss]
PS1+="$green\u@\h" # user@host
PS1+="$blue\w\$$reset " # workingdir$

export PS1
unset green blue dim reset
```

Comment: My PS1 calls a command that printf escape sequences causing OP's problem. Only this solution fixes the issue for me.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for to put in my inpurc `set vi-ins-mode-string "${green}I ${white}|"`

Comment: this worked for me and it's pretty elegant as well

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in other answers, non-printable sequences such as `\e[0;30m` should be wrapped with `\[...\]`.

Additionally (and what I don't see mentioned yet) is it seems that `\r\n` should be *outside* of the `\[...\]` if you have a multi-line prompt. It took me some of trial and error to finally figure that out.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like an issue with your `COLUMNS` & `LINES` environment variable settings. When you resize the window they're typically set automatically by gnome-terminal (I believe) you can force them to be manually set by issuing the command `resize`.

#### Example

If I resize my gnome-terminal to 79x17 my variables show up like so:

```
$ echo $COLUMNS; echo $LINES
79
17
```

I can force it like so:

```
$ resize
COLUMNS=79;
LINES=17;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't help.

Comment: This fixed my issue it was not wrapping lines correctly after I ran the command "screen".  Thanks!!

Comment: What package does the command `resize` come from?

Comment: @till - think it's part of X11 - https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwh

Answer (score 9):

To prevent wrapping, you can also increase the number of columns using, e.g.

```
stty columns 120
```

Comment: not a very good idea, it messed up vim brutally

Comment: Use rmam / smam as provided by other answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558771/140633

Answer (score 6):

Also the same issue can be caused by using wide unicode symbols (like from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812608/1657819).
Here is the snippet causing the problem (mind the `$Green` and `$Red` are properly escaped color strings):

```
FancyX='\342\234\227'
Checkmark='\342\234\223'


# Add a bright white exit status for the last command
PS1="$White\$? "
# If it was successful, print a green check mark. Otherwise, print
# a red X.
if [[ $Last_Command == 0 ]]; then
    PS1+="$Green$Checkmark "
else
    PS1+="$Red$FancyX "
fi
```

Bash cannot calculate the length correctly, so easiest way could be to escape 2 out of three parts of those wide symbols.

```
FancyX='\[\342\234\]\227'
Checkmark='\[\342\234\]\223'
```

Comment: Makes sense. What I guess is that bash counts characters. Because the X takes one char but is written as 3, then one needs to enclose 2 of them to fix counting.  @blauhirn answer also explains how to do in a function with `\001` and `\002`.

Comment: FYI, this is how you figure out how to output multi-byte unicode characters in this format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/602924/520567

Comment: If you get your prompt set up correctly, you might also see these symptoms if there's a mismatch between bash and your terminal.  For example, I had changed my LANG variable from the default of en_US.utf8 to en_US.iso88591 in order to work on some data in the Latin-1 character set, and I had forgotten to change it back when I was done.

Answer (score 3):

**`tput smam`**

On Ubuntu 19.10 in a Gnome terminal, which has `TERM=xterm-256color`, this emits the exact escape sequence that makes the terminal wrap lines:

```
tput smam
```

You can see what that escape is with:

```
tput smam | hd
```

Resetting the terminal state with:

```
reset
```

also seems to have the effect of setting `tput smam`.

The man page:

```
man terminfo
```

documents `smam` and its opposite `rmam`:

```
       enter_am_mode   smam   SA   turn on automatic margins
       exit_am_mode    rmam   RA   turn off automatic margins
```

Note however that certain terminals don't have that capability, e.g. inside `tmux` we have `TERM=screen-265color` and `smam` does not appear on the list of capabilities:

```
infocmp
```

and so `tput smam` doesn't print anything.

I'm not sure how, but [QEMU was able to change the line wrap state of tmux while `tput` wasn't](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/issues/110).

Comment: Under tmux and screen, `setterm --linewrap=off` still works.  Probably hard-coded to `\033[?7l` and `\033[?7h` without consulting termcap/terminfo?

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin thanks for this info. I'm going to try it out next time it starts hurting me! :-) Gotta (re)learn where the escape code list is documented.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin OK, `Esc[?7l` is what it emits according to `hd` and its name is DECAWM according to http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 almost identical Archlinux setups and after I switched one to "powerline" PS1 with Unicode characters I've got the same problem. It turned out that on affected laptop I was missing /etc/locale.conf file

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
```

once I've copied it over, terminal became Unicode-aware and "line overlap" problem went away.

Comment: This answer saved me. I had totally forgotten that I had put LC_ALL=C in my .bashrc. With Starship, this was causing prompt issues. Switching to UTF-8 (which is what I should have used in the FIRST place) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this article, I've got my prompt working very nicely. And when combined with gitprompt (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), I get the exact things I want.

```
PS1_RESET='\001$(tput sgr0)\002'
PS1_ERROR='$(code=${?##0};echo ${code:+\001$(tput setaf 1)\002[${code}]\ })'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_SHLVL='\001$(tput setaf 4)\002($SHLVL) '"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_DATE='\001$(tput setaf 5)\002\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} '"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_USER='\001$(tput setaf 6)\002\u'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_AT='\001$(tput sgr0)\002@'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_HOST='\001$(tput setaf 2)\002\h'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_COLON='\001$(tput sgr0)\002:'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_PATH='\001$(tput setaf 3)\002\w'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_GIT='$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")'"$PS1_RESET"
PS1_PROMPT=' \\$ '
PS1_COMBINED=$PS1_ERROR$PS1_SHLVL$PS1_DATE$PS1_USER$PS1_AT$PS1_HOST$PS1_COLON$PS1_PATH
export PS1="$PS1_COMBINED"

GIT_PS1_COMPRESSSPARSESTATE=
GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE=
GIT_PS1_HIDE_IF_PWD_IGNORED=yes
GIT_PS1_OMITSPARSESTATE=
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=yes
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
GIT_PS1_STATESEPARATOR=" "
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PS1_COMBINED" "$PS1_PROMPT"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The question asked is for the  `Bash` shell interpreter, as like many of the other questions on similar topic. None, if not few, point to on how to do it on the `Zsh` shell interpreter.

`\[ ... \]` or `\001 ... \002` won't work with `.zshrc`. For `Zsh`, the special characters are `%{` and `%}`. For example, here is how you would configure your prompt with colors in `.zshrc` :

```
promptText="megh$ "
PS1="%{$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 3)%}$promptText%{$(tput sgr0)%}"
```

Link to [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Simple-Prompt-Escapes:%7E:text=Include%20a%20string%20as%20a%20literal%20escape%20sequence.%20The%20string%20within%20the%20braces%20should%20not%20change%20the%20cursor%20position.%20Brace%20pairs%20can%20nest.)