# Bash doesn't calculate prompt length correctly

Tags: bash, prompt

I've googled around quite a bit on this problem and found a few related problems, like this one: [Terminal prompt not wrapping correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly).

My problem is that bash doesn't calculate the length of the prompt correctly, which messes it up when I do things like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> to scroll through history. This is basically how it should look (without colors).

```
✔ name@machine ~

01:09 $
```

When I for example scroll through previous commands with up-arrow, some character gets stuck in the prompt:

```
✔ name@machine ~

01:09 $m
```

Sometimes I also get other weird behaviour, like some of the prompt being overwritten (it all goes away when I reload it). My prompt looks like this:

```
GIT_PROMPT_START_USER="\n_LAST_COMMAND_INDICATOR_ \[$Magenta\]\u\[$Orange\]@\[$White\]\h \[$Yellow\]\[$PathShort\]\[$ResetColor\]"

GIT_PROMPT_END_USER="\n\[$Blue\]$Time12a\[$ResetColor\] $ "
```

I use something called `git-bash-prompt`: >https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt>.

I think what is messing it up is the time variable, which is defined in another file:

```
Time12a="\$(date +%H:%M)"
```

I've tried both `\[$Time12a\]` and `$Time12a` in `GIT_PROMPT_END_USER`, but none of them seem to work. My guess is that bash calculates it wrong because `$Time12a` represents 5 characters (hh:mm).

How does bash calculate the length of this? Is it possible to explicitly set the length for bash? Answers very appreciated!

Comment: You're excluding `$PathShort` from the length calculation (it's wrapped in `\[…\]`). Have you checked if the prompt length offset differs when `$ShortPath` is longer than one character?

Comment: Good catch! Though I don't think it makes a difference (I haven't noticed any, and it works good now), probably because it's on another line.

Answer (score 5):

So I found out what messed it up, and it was not what I expected :)

It was actually the \[$ResetColor\] that bash for some reason used to count the length forward one step (bash thought my prompt was 1 step longer).

The variable was defined by "bash-git-prompt" along with all the other colors (see the link to the git-repo in the question if you want to look into it). Anyways, the fix was easy. I just overrode their definition with my own:

```
ResetColor=$(tput sgr0)
```

Fixed!

(Just btw if somebody else is also having this problem, I have already overridden all the other colors I used with my own definitions using $COLOR=$(tput setaf X) where COLOR is the color you want and X is that color's xterm-256 number.)