# Bash prompt over-writing current line

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I am having similar problems to this thread here, with the command line overwriting the line and my up arrow overwriting all of the text.

[Terminal prompt not wrapping correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/terminal-prompt-not-wrapping-correctly)

When I run

```
$ shopt  | grep checkwinsize
checkwinsize    on
```

It seems like the issue is caused by not wrapping the right parts of the ps1 part of my bashrc. script in []. i have tried to follow the explanations in the other threads, but it hasn't seemed to help.

This is the part of my bashrc. script.

```
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Is there anything wrong with my bashrc. script which is causing this problem?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 Cinnamon version 3.6.7 and 4.13.0-36-generic kernel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this or see any problems with your script, though I might be missing something.

I would first ensure that the issue is actually with this part of your bashrc. Run 'echo $PS1' to check if the prompt is being modified elsewhere. To be sure, see if the problem still occurs after running:

```
bash -noprofile -norc
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

If the issue is still present, the culprit may be your terminal emulator. Check that the value of '$TERM' is correct for the terminal emulator you use, and try using a different one. You might also try reinitialising the terminal and setting PS1 manually. Assuming you are using xterm:

```
TERM=xterm
tset $TERM
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```