# Cursor appears at the beginning of command line

Tags: prompt

I'm having difficulty with specifying `PS1` on Ubuntu 18.04.5. I use the following code in my `.bashrc` file and the result looks *exactly* as it should.

```
export PS1=$'\e[38;5;046m \u00AB\D{%y-%m-%d}\u00BB-[\D{%H:%M:%S}]-{\W}\e[1m\e[38;5;196m>\e[38;5;226m>\e[38;5;046m>\e[38;5;255m\e[0m '
```

[image]

The problem is that my cursor is at the *beginning* of the command line and not after the *>>>*. Curiously, if I set my terminal to full screen, the cursor appears where it should. Is there an obvious error in my `PS1` definition?

Comment: Just FYI, I'm on ubuntu 19.10 and it works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is over 80 characters long, and bash doesn't know fully how to parse the escape sequences.  In particular, it thinks there is a line wrap going on, and it tries to produce it or compensate for it.

As for how to fix it?  Put explicit newlines into your PS1.

I tried appending `\e7\eM\n\e8` and it seemed to, mostly, work.  In case you are wondering: `\e7` is save position.  `\eM` is "reverse index", basically a reverse linefeed.  `\n` is a newline, and `\e8` is restore position.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, David! This is a great workaround (+1). Wrapping non-printable characters in `\[` and `\]` seems to prevent the problem in the first place, as described in the [solution given above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105974/428212).